# JS menu stops working when navigating to a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some issues with my JS menu. When the page loads the menu work great, and as expected. You click the option, then it displays the menu items.

However, once I click one of the menu items and navigate to a different page the menu stops working! When you click on the icon, the menu no longer appears. The page just sits there. When i look try debug in chrome it no longer "hits" the code.

I have noticed that if i refresh that page, the menu works again as expected :/

My JS code is below, what am I missing for this kind of issue to arise?

I have created a pen for this - http://codepen.io/alr3id/pen/bwdKxL

```
function MyMenus(jQuery) {
  $(".p-menu-icon").on("click", function(event) {
     var e = $(this).next(".p-menu");
     e.hasClass("p-menu_open") || $(document).trigger("click"),
     $(".p-modal-bg").toggleClass("p-modal-bg_active"),
     e.toggleClass("p-menu_open"),
     event.stopPropagation()
  });

  // Removes the menu open class.
  $(document).on("click", function(t) {
     var e = $(t.target)
       , i = 1 === e.closest("p-menu").length;
     i || ($(".p-menu.p-menu_open").removeClass("p-menu_open"),
     $(".p-modal-bg").removeClass("p-modal-bg_active"))
  });
}

// Load
$(document).ready(MyMenus);
```

Below is the HTML for the Menu

```
<nav class="p">
  <div class="p-modal-bg"></div>

  <div class="p-property">
    <a class="p-property-name" href="/">
      Logo Here
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="p-user">
    <a class="p-menu-icon">
      <div class="icon icon-navigator-toggle"></div>
    </a>

    <div class="p-menu p-menu_navigator">
      <a class="p-menu-item p-menu-item_dashboard" href="/">Dashboard</a>
      <a class="p-menu-item p-menu-item_orders" href="/orders">My orders</a>
      <a class="p-menu-item p-menu-item_back-bar" href="/products">Products</a>
    </div>

    <a class="p-menu-icon p-menu-icon_account">
      <div class="p-user-avatar_container">
        <img alt="Example user" class="gravatar" src="{image here}">
      </div>
    </a>

    <div class="p-menu p-menu_account">
      <div class="p-menu-item_account-details">
        <div class="p-user-avatar_container">
          <img alt="Example user" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/{image here}">
        </div>
        <div class="p-account-details-name">
          Example User
        </div>
        <div class="p-account-details-email">example@example.com</div>
      </div>
      <a class="p-menu-item p-menu-item_settings" href="account">Account settings</a>
      <a class="p-menu-item p-menu-item_messages" href="#">Messages</a>
      <a class="p-menu-item p-menu-item_logout" href="#">Sign out</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Try to explain a bit more what goes wrong. "stops working" is to vague for us to analyze the problem.

Comment: Hi Ruden, i have updated the post. Cheers.

Comment: Might be a silly question, but just in case - script is included on that page as well? :)

Comment: haha, not a silly question at all its easily missed. But yeah its on the page, its just not hitting it. Unless its the HTML thats at fault :/

Comment: I have added the HTML for the nav menu

Comment: I have noticed that if i refresh that page, the menu works again as expected :/

Comment: Could you add necessary CSS code so it actually shows/hides the menu?

Comment: I have added a link to a pen with has all the code :) Also ran a test on the code and am getting **Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.**

Comment: How do you navigate to the page? Do you load it via XHR?

Comment: I am using rails, and this is included on the layout page. I run the rails server, then open localhost in my browser :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is something I didn't even consider, it turns out this issue is down to Rails and Turbolinks!

Due to the way Turbolinks loads pages it screws up

```
$(document).ready
```

to fix this you need to use...

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load"
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the JS file you are using in this page (new page where it stuck) too ? Try adding the code on another file also or move your js code to another js file and import it on that page.

Comment: It's included on all pages as it's a layout page in rails. If i refresh the page it then works.

Comment: are you concerning  layout page as css here ? If so you should add java-script too.

Answer (score 0):

Since it works at freshly loaded page the code itself shouldn't be a problem.
What comes to mind are class changes. Open up your browser's inspector and check if there are any class name changes that would resolve in loosing a listener.

Also try putting some `console.log()` inside each function so you are sure that both events aren't getting fired one after another.

Comment: Added in a console.log("clicked') just after the initial click. Once again it works until i move to a different page :/

Comment: Are there any class changes? (loosing p-menu-icon class name)
Also add console.log inside the MyMenus function to check if it loads.

Comment: turns out its bloody Turbolinke that's causing the issue :/